Understanding method overriding and constructor behavior in Java inheritance
I'm trying to understand the behavior of method overriding, constructor calls, and variable shadowing in Java inheritance. I have the following code
class Base {
    int id = 1000; //Line n1

    Base() {
        Base(); //Line n2
    }

    void Base() { //Line n3
        System.out.println(++id); //Line n4
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    int id = 2000; //Line n5

    Derived() {} //Line n6

    void Base() { //Line n7
        System.out.println(--id); //Line n8
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Derived(); //Line n9
    }
}

When I run this code, it outputs -1.
I understand that Derived extends Base, and both classes have an id variable and a Base() method. The order is as follow

call constructor of Derived
call constructor of Base
call Base() method, due to method overriding, the method in the child class is executed.

Therefor, in my opinion, the result will be 1001.

This question is similar to: why doesn't my field get initialized to the value I gave it. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it has a little bit different. my question have id attribute on both classes while the linked question only have attribute on derived class.

Same problem. Line n8 is referencing the field in line n5, not in n1. And the field in line n5 is not initialized yet, as indicated in the duplicate question.

you can specify more in deepth for me. Because I have read the answer on linked question. I don't understand.

See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577430/what-is-object-field-initialization-and-constructor-order-in-java. The field Derived.id is not initialized at the time the line System.out.println(--id); at marker "n8" is called.

by the way, id from Derived is not the same as from Base, you could (should) rename one of these (to avoid confusion)-- for constructor calls, see Java Language Specification 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances

BTW2 - not recommended to have a method with the same name as a constructor, that is, the class name; also according Java Naming Convention, method names should start with lowercase

@Progman, thanks

This is because of the way java constructors are working.
The first instruction of a constructor will always be this.super(), event if not written in your code.
While this.super() is called, variables aren't affected and have their default value (which is 0 for ints).
So, you are removing 1 to id (that equals 0).
You can test with this code:
class Base {
    int id = 1000;

    Base() {
        System.out.println("Base constructor called");
        Base();
    }

    void Base() {
        System.out.println("Base called");
        System.out.println(++this.id);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    int id = 2000;

    Derived() {
        System.out.println("==Super finished==");
        Base();
    }

    void Base() {
        System.out.println("Derived base called");
        System.out.println(--this.id);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived();
    }
}

The output will be :
Base constructor called
Derived base called
-1
==Super finished==
Derived base called
1999

However, if your main was :
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Base();
    }
}

then, your output would be the following :
Base constructor called
Base called
1001

This is because, in that case:

The constructor will, first of all, call this.super() (the constructor of the Object object)
Then, variables will be initialized (since this.super() has been called)
Finally, you will sysout id + 1.


The behavior described here may change in future versions of Java, beyond Java 23. Work is underway to make constructors more flexible. See JEP 482: Flexible Constructor Bodies (Second Preview).

I'm only guessing, but JEP 447 may change the behavior you describe.

This is indeed possible since Java 22 (I didn't know).
However, it will still be, by default, the first instruction called in the constructor, and you can't call/use any methods or attributes until supper called

"The first instruction of a constructor will always be this.super()" unless there is a call to another constructor of same class (this(...)) which then may call the constructor of its superclass; but anyway the code of parents constructor is executed before the one of the actual class, that is, the parents are initialized first ((ignoring JEP 447))

@VOLTIS, "variables aren't affected and have their default value (which is 0 for ints)." you can explain more to me. why this statement Base base2 = new Base(); print 1001, According to your explain, it will be 1

@happy because the Base constructor will call this.super() (which basically do nothing), and THEN call this.Base. So, since the super() has been called, variables have their valued affected before trying to increment id.

@VOLTIS , yep, you can add information about my question to your answer?.

@happy done :) I hope it is clear enough now !

totally clear! thank you so much
